How to color a specific internal region?
I am trying to color the region in the left diagram like in the right diagram. Currently, my TikZ code can achieve the left diagram, but I'm not quite sure how to do the right one.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define node and edge styles
\tikzset{
  whitenode/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1.5pt},
  blackedge/.style={thick}
}
    \node [whitenode] (u) at (0, 2) {$u$};
    \node [whitenode] (v) at (0, -2) {$v$};
    \node [whitenode] (x) at (-2, 0.5) {$x$};
    \node [whitenode] (y) at (-2, -0.5) {$y$};
    \node [whitenode] (w) at (2, 0.5) {$w$};
    \node [whitenode] (z) at (2, -0.5) {$z$};

    % Draw the curved edges
    \draw [blackedge, in=135, out=165, looseness=1.75] (u) to (y);
    \draw [blackedge, in=-165, out=-135, looseness=1.75] (x) to (v);
    \draw [blackedge, in=45, out=15, looseness=1.75] (u) to (z);
    \draw [blackedge, in=-15, out=-45, looseness=1.75] (w) to (v);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}




Quick and dirty hack: fill your curves and then cover the remaining space with an additional shape
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define node and edge styles
\tikzset{
  whitenode/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=1.5pt},
  blackedge/.style={thick}
}

    \coordinate (u) at (0, 2);
    \coordinate (v) at (0, -2);
    \coordinate (x) at (-2, 0.5);
    \coordinate (y) at (-2, -0.5);
    \coordinate (w) at (2, 0.5);
    \coordinate (z) at (2, -0.5);

    % Draw the curved edges
    \draw 
      [blackedge, fill=lightgray]
      [in=135, out=165, looseness=1.75] (u) to (y)  
      [in=-165, out=-135, looseness=1.75] (x) to (v) 
      [in=45, out=15, looseness=1.75] (u) to (z)
      [in=-15, out=-45, looseness=1.75] (w) to (v);
      
    \fill[lightgray] (v) -- (z) -- (w) -- (u) -- (x) -- (y) -- (v) ;  
      
    \node [whitenode] at (u) {$u$};
    \node [whitenode] at (v) {$v$};
    \node [whitenode] at (x) {$x$};
    \node [whitenode] at (y) {$y$};
    \node [whitenode] at (w) {$w$};
    \node [whitenode] at (z) {$z$};      
    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Can also be combined into one fill like this: \draw  [blackedge, fill=lightgray] (u) to[in=135, out=165, looseness=1.75] (y)   (x) to[in=-165, out=-135, looseness=1.75] (v)  (z) to[in=15, out=45, looseness=1.75] (u) (v) to[in=-45, out=-15, looseness=1.75] (w) (v) -- (z) -- (w) -- (u) -- (x) -- (y) -- (v);   

@hpekristiansen Won't this show the edge of the helper shape? https://i.sstatic.net/M6nnjnPp.png

Yes you are right. To do the fill in one command, it is needed to do the fill without draw and then the draw in a separate command.
